# How can i add Gradient colour for button tint in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uibutton, gradient

is there any solution to apply tint colour as a gradient in swift

my button has a simple white icon I want to change it to a gradient colour

Comment: Like other `UIView` subclasses,`UIButton` has a `tintColor` property. However, it takes a `UIColor` A gradient is not a simple color, and so can't be used as a tint color.

You want to apply a gradient color to a monochrome image in your button? Are you installing the image into the button's `imageView` property?

Comment: Please share the UI of the button that you have so people can help you easily.

Comment: A gradient is not a color, and can't be used as a tint color. Your question does not make sense. You need to show an example of the effect you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my answer according to [Duncan C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c) comment.

You can modify your image before setting it to button.

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func drawLinearGradient(colors: [CGColor], startingPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.size)
        
        var shouldReturnNil = false
        let gradientImage = renderer.image { context in
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
            context.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

            context.cgContext.setBlendMode(.normal)
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

            // Create gradient
            let colors = colors as CFArray
            let colorsSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            
            guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorsSpace, colors: colors, locations: nil) else {
                shouldReturnNil = true
                return
            }

            // Apply gradient
            guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
                shouldReturnNil = true
                print("Couldn't get cgImage of UIImage.")
                return
            }
            
            context.cgContext.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage)
            context.cgContext.drawLinearGradient(
                gradient,
                start: endPoint,
                end: startingPoint,
                options: .init(rawValue: 0)
            )
        }

        return shouldReturnNil ? nil : gradientImage
    }
    
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "<your_image_name>") else { return }
v.image = image.drawLinearGradient(
    colors: [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor],
    startingPoint: .init(x: image.size.width / 2, y: 0),
    endPoint: .init(x: image.size.width / 2, y: image.size.height)
)
button.setImage(gradientImage, for: .normal)
```

This code produces result like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, this is not useful for me cause I want to change the tint colour not an image

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly understand meaning of gradient?

Comment: To the OP: This answer will take the opaque parts of the source image and draw them using a linear gradient. That seems like what you are asking for, given that you say "my button has a simple white icon I want to change it to a gradient colour". This will convert a monochrome image to a color gradient image. If it's not what you want then you will need to explain what you DO want.

Comment: BTW, you're supposed to use a `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` for offscreen drawing in modern code, not `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. See [this link](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/uigraphicsimagerenderer-fe40edc3a464)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too
but for now
if you wanna change the text color it works.
like you convert image into pattern color by this code

/*

```
class gradiunTitle : UIButton  {

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
      }
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
      }
   private func setup() {
       let gradient = getGradientLayer(bounds: self.bounds)
      self.setTitleColor(gradientColor(bounds: self.bounds, gradientLayer: gradient), for: .normal)
       self.tintColor = gradientColor(bounds: self.frame, gradientLayer: gradient)
      }
    func getGradientLayer(bounds : CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer{
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    //order of gradient colors
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    return gradient
    }
    
    func gradientColor(bounds: CGRect, gradientLayer :CAGradientLayer) -> UIColor? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return UIColor(patternImage: image!)
    }
}
```

*/

Comment: thanks for your response, this is not my solution I want to change the tint colour, not the title colour.